# data loading performance issue in databricks

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm inserting data into delta table in azure databricks with 2 million records and execution is taking 3 hours

here is my code

```
df.write.format("delta").option("overwriteSchema", "true").mode("append").saveAsTable("TableName")
```

my cluster has RAM of 14 GB and 4 nodes with two workers

how can i improve the data loading performance?

Comment: One simple optimization (without knowledge about the full transformation pipeline), is to persist your results (so to compute the pipeline already before writing) in memory before writing them back. 

This way you can differentiate weather the bottleneck is computation or storage.

Comment: hi ,  Especially when dealing with large datasets. If possible, partition your data. Partitioning can significantly improve your query performance  and also consider scaling your cluster up by increasing the number of nodes or the instance type to improve processing power and memory.

Comment: another way,  try to optimise your dataframe operations before writing to the delta table. For example, selecting only necessary columns, and other transformations that could reduce the data size or processing time.

Comment: Can you share the execution plan before the .write here

Comment: I'm reading it from csv file and it has 9807172 rows